# Does IncludeDirectory Detect All Minified Versions on Production in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a lot of javascript files on my Script folder. Originally, my RegisterBundles is this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
    }
```

But since I have a lot of other Javascript files under my Script folder, I want to shortcut everything into this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js", true));
```

Since I think they work the same. But do they really work the same? And will MVC convert all minified versions once in Productions?